# How to make casefold() work on certain Arabic unicodes

Tags: python, unicode, arabic, case-insensitive

I've got some issues with detecting the "equality" in Python 2.7 of some Arabic pairs of words:

1. أكثر vs اكثر
2. قائمة vs قائمه
3. إنشاء vs انشاء

The elements of each pair are not really identical, but they are written with different cases. An useful analogy for me (I don't know any Arabic) is *Word* vs *word*. They are not identical, but if I lowercase both of them, I'll obtain *word* vs *word*, which are identical. That's what I want to obtain from these 3 pairs of Arabic words.

I'm going to exemplify what I tried by now using the first pair (1. أكثر vs اكثر). By the way, the meaning of both Arabic words from the first pair is <s>"menu"</s> "more", but they have different cases (as a parallel: <s>*Menu* vs *menu*</s> *More* vs *more*). I don't know Arabic at all nor Arabic rules, so if someone who knows Arabic can confirm that those words are "identical" it would be great.

```
str1 = u'أكثر'
str2 = u'اكثر'
```

So what I'm trying to do is to bring `str1` and `str2` to the same form (if possible), so I want a function which produce the same output for both strings:

```
transform(str1) == transform(str2)
```

In English this can be achieved easily:

```
a = u'More'
b = u'more'

def transform(text):
    return text.lower()

>>> transform(a) == transform(b)
>>> True
```

But, of course, this doesn't work for Arabic as there are no such things like lower case or upper case.

```
>>> str1
u'\u0623\u0643\u062b\u0631'

>>> str2
u'\u0627\u0643\u062b\u0631'
```

Note that only the first character differs in the unicode representation.

I also normalized the strings using:

```
import unicodedata

>>> n_str1 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', str1)
>>> n_str2 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', str2)

>>> n_str1
u'\u0627\u0654\u0643\u062b\u0631'

>>> n_str2
u'\u0627\u0643\u062b\u0631'
```

As you already noticed:

```
>>> n_str1 == n_str2
False
```

After that, I tried to use unicode.casefold() but it isn't available in Python 2. I've installed py2casefold library but it I didn't manage to obtain the equality between the strings. So I tried to use Python 3's unicode.casefold() but without any luck:

```
>>> str1.casefold() == str2.casefold()
False

>>> n_str1.casefold() == n_str2.casefold()
False
```

A solution for this in Python 2 would be perfect, but it would be great in Python 3 too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

These words are not identical: u'أكثر' and u'اكثر' are not the same. The first  letter in the first word has the letter Alif with Hamazah on top of it, perhaps you couldn't notice that due to the small size of the glyph:

[image: Alif with Hamaza]

The first letter in the second word, however, is Alif *(from right-to-left):

[image: Alif]

And hence they don't compare equal. Each of these letters is represented by its own Unicode character code point. They don't compare equal from the perspective of the language too:

```
>>> u'أكثر'; u'اكثر'
u'\u0623\u0643\u062b\u0631'
u'\u0627\u0643\u062b\u0631'
```

> They are not identical, but if I lowercase both of them, I'll obtain word vs word, which are identical. That's what I want to obtain from these 3 pairs of Arabic words.

There's no lower or upper case in Arabic. The words that you have in your hands are not the same, they have different letters. Some of the words  have correct spelling while others have incorrect spelling. They may seem to be the same, but for Arabic readers they also may consider them to be the same, for language freaks, they're not the same. But they convey the meaning, your list of Arabic words in English roughly looks like this:

1- more, moore

2- menu, manu

3- establish, estblish

> I'm going to exemplify what I tried by now using the first pair (1. أكثر vs اكثر). By the way, the meaning of both Arabic words from the first pair is "menu", but they have different cases (as a parallel: Menu vs menu)

No, **أكثر** means *more*. Your second pair means *menu*, but there's no such thing as Menu or menu in Arabic. I couldn't delve into details, because this would be off topic.

Comment: Thank you, @direprobs for shedding some light here, for your detailed explanation. What are you saying is that it's not possible to determine that both words convey to the same meaning in English using a programming language? Both Arabic words are possible user inputs. Should I map the English word with all its Arabic translations (2 in this case) and perform a search for each input to obtain the word in English (in this case "more")? I hoped I can store 1 AR form of the word for 1 English word, and transform the user input somehow for obtaining that 1 AR form (which is mapped to the EN word).

Comment: @svecax "What are you saying is that it's not possible to determine that both words convey to the same meaning in English using a programming language?"  No, that's not what I meant. Basically, you have words that can be written in different forms, one of which is correct and others are similar but not exactly the same and have incorrect spellings. As to how to match these words, I'm not sure what is needed. Maybe use a list of similar words? For ex. `words = [u'أكثر', u'اكثر']`  and then check the inputted word taking if it's in the list to take actions: `if input_word in words: ...`

Comment: I edited a bit the description so it reflects the reality, according to the @direprobs observations. Thanks again. I will come back when I will find a proper solution for this.